# DB2: Use dynamic FROM Clause in Select

Tags: sql, db2, abap, dynamic-sql

given is the current SELECT Statement with opening the cursor.
Is it possible to define a Variable for the View Name and use it whilst able to keep Cursor Functionality?

```
    EXEC SQL .
      OPEN dbcur FOR SELECT
         PERSID,
         PERSNR,
         GVON,
            FROM TEST_DB0T.TS$$004
    ENDEXEC.

Find out if using Dynamic FROM Clause is possible in the given Scenario
```

Comment: Do you insist on using `EXEC SQL` here? This case seems trivial enough to do it with OpenSQL. Yes, [it has cursors](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapopen_cursor.htm).

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean, this request is for an external database so is openSQL for this possible?

Comment: When it's not the database your SAP system runs on, then you might be able to access it as a [secondary database connection](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenopensql_multiconnect.htm). Secondary connections need to be registered system-wide in transaction DBCON. You can then use them in any ABAP database statement like this:  `SELECT ... CONNECTION your_db2_connection_name`

Comment: Why don't you use ADBC instead?

Comment: We already defined Database Connection in DBCON. As described in my initial Post, we have different Views which we need to access dynamically. 
So far we dont have experiences with ADBC so this wasn't tried....

Comment: please describe your requirement in more detail: where these views are defined (local or remote system), who will be the consumers of those views and what you put into word "dynamically"